# Многопоточная обработка JTree

Tags: многопоточность, jtree, java

Есть следующий класс, реализующий интерфейс Runnable:

```
public class TreeHandler implements Runnable {
    private String name;
    private JTree tree;
    private Tree model;

    public TreeHandler(String name, JTree tree) {
        this.name = name;
        this.tree = tree;
        model = (Tree)tree.getModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Node node;
        String nodeName;
        int nodeNum;
        System.out.println(name + " started");
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(name + " want to find node for handling");
            synchronized (tree) {
                while (true) {
                    Node root = (Node)(model.getRoot());
                    if (root == null || !isNumber(root)) {
                        System.out.println(name + " ended job");
                        return;
                    }
                    System.out.println(name + " get tree and searching...");
                    node = model.findNode(root, tester);
                    if (node != null)
                        break;
                    System.out.println("For that time there are no nodes, " + name + " waiting...");
                    try {
                        tree.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(name + " found node " + node);
                nodeName = node.toString();
                nodeNum = Integer.parseInt(nodeName);
                model.setData(node, this.name + " start with " + nodeName);
                updateTree();
            }
            System.out.println(name + " handling " + nodeName);
            nodeNum = (int)(nodeNum > 47 ? 47-Math.random() * 7 : nodeNum < 20 ? 20 : nodeNum);
            fibo(nodeNum);
            System.out.println(name + " handled " + nodeName);
            synchronized (tree) {
                model.setData(node, name + " finished with " + nodeName);
                updateTree();
                tree.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isNumber(Object node) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(node.toString());
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isFinished(Object node) {
        return node.toString().indexOf("finish") >= 0;
    }

    public int fibo(int n) {
        if (n <= 0)
            return 0;
        else if (n == 1 || n == 2)
            return n;
        else
            return fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2);
    }

    Predicate<Node> tester = (node)->{
        if (!isNumber(node))
            return false;
        Iterator<Node> itr = model.iterator(node);
        itr.next();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            if (!isFinished(itr.next()))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    };

    void updateTree() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tree.updateUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Данный код предназначается для демонстрировации работы многопоточности в Java. Но, насколько я понимаю, блок `synchronized(tree)` указывает на то, что компонент JTree будет обрабатываться только одним потоком в один момент времени, что в данном случае исключает целесообразность применения нескольких потоков для обработки данного дерева. Можно ли как-то изменить данный код, чтобы `synchronized` или его аналог ограничивал доступ одного потока только к одному узлу, а не ко всему дереву в целом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы не меняете структуру дерева, можно, например, синхронизироваться по самому узлу.

Comment: А можно, пожалуйста, немного поконкретней?